# ARM Template deployment issue - set AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType to 'Files'

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am building and deploying a combination of Logic App (Consumption) and Azure Function (4.x, .NET 6) through YAML pipelines using ARM templates. The pipeline is building fine. During the deployment stage the `AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2` Logic App task is giving following error:

`##[error]Conflict: System.InvalidOperationException: Runtime keys are stored on blob storage. This API doesn't support this configuration. Please change Environment variable AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType value to 'Files'`

On adding the suggested environment variable, deployment is successful but the logic app fails during execution because the secrets are read from Key Vault.

**Update - Oct 2**:

I have zeroed-in the error to the following line in the ARM template

```
"uri": "[listsecrets(variables('webhook_function_name'),'2015-08-01').trigger_url]"
```

which is part of defining the step in the Logic App to invoke the Web hook Azure function. Hard coding the url shows me a green on deployment. But as expected the step doesn't run during execution.

Any alternative syntax that I should use to get the dynamic function url?

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible Solution

The secrets that are affected by the **AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType** setting are only the secrets related to the function app/Logic app, such as the master key.

When it comes to accessing secrets in the key vault from your logic app & function app, you will need to add an access policy or RBAC entry in the key vault.

You should also make sure that managed identity is used when interacting with the key vault.

Comment: Probably this one is not about the Keyvault access. I have updated the original question with some more information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like have a `misconfiguration`.

By default when a `Azure function` starts it looks for a `function key` in `the file system` inside `App Service`.

If your existing configuration is to use the `Azure Blob Storage` or `Azure key vault` for the `secret storage` then they will look there.

as per this is seems like the mismatch in the `expected configuration`

these are the following steps to fix the issue:

1. setup the enviornment variable: In your ARM template for the Azure Function, ensure that you set the environment variable `AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType` to `Files`. This is to satisfy the Azure Functions runtime.
2. setup `secrets` rightway: the `listsecrets` error probably because of `API` version issue, as per your code the version is older try to update the line with this:

   "uri": "[listsecrets(variables('webhook_function_name'), '2016-08-01').trigger_url]"

   or also change the version to `2018-11-01`
3. also check the `permission` is right or not: your `Logic App` also needs a permission to list the `Secrets` of the `Azure Function`. So once check that the necessary permission on the `Azure Function` are provided.
4. `secrets` use case: as you mentioned that the `secrets` are read from the `Azure Key Valut`, so as per this you might need to move the `Azure Function Secret` to `Key Valut`. Also as per this update the `AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType` to `KeyVault`, as per the changes you also need to update the necessory configraton for the `Azure Function` to read from the `Key Valte`.